# Add column to existing table in SQL with IF/ ELSE Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, pgadmin-4

I am suing PgAdmin4
I have a table called `Development`. This table contains a column called `Customer`. I want to create a new column called `Target` which is equal to 1 when the Customer is `null` and `0` otherwise.

Here is my code:

```
ALTER TABLE development ADD COLUMN Target INTEGER;

IF Customer IS NULL then
  SET Target = 1;
else
  SET Target = 0;
END if;
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 3: IF Customer IS NULL then
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 53
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `update` statement with a `case` expression:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET target = CASE WHEN customer IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 4):

Most databases support generated columns.  The syntax is something like this:

```
alter table development add column int generated always as
    (case when customer is null then 1 else 0 end);
```

The exact syntax varies by database.

This is much more powerful than adding a new column to the table, because a generated column always has the correct value -- even without an `update`.